# After server migration to new, blank page loaded

Tags: java, angular, browser, server

We recently migrated openstack to VMC2 server and after production deployment observed a blank page loaded. The user had to clear the cache and then it worked. But what could be the possibility behind this as our users don't seem to like clearing the cache and we have n number of complaints received on this.

Comment: Sometimes these issue happens due to polyfills. Browser catch that locally. So try to change that.

Comment: can you pls explain in detail? how to change and to what?